# How to visualize Microsoft Power BI in H2?

Tags: connection, powerbi, integration, visualization, h2

I'm trying to connect my h2 database with Power BI, but I'm not able to see any connector for this database. Is there any other way to connect h2 database with Power BI?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can connect through ODBC. See [Connect to data using generic interfaces in Power BI Desktop](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/desktop-connect-using-generic-interfaces) and [H2 ODBC Driver](http://www.h2database.com/html/advanced.html#odbc_driver).

Comment: Thanks a ton, will follow this instruction. is there any youtube video available for this?